# How to set the color of a v-icon which is disabled without a gnarly css selector and !important?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

It is easy to set the color of a v-icon simply by setting the color prop:

```
<v-icon color="red">home</v-icon>
```

However I'm having problems formatting disabled icons. There are no properties of v-icons specific to disabled states, so it seems we must resort to css selectors. For example, in order to set the opacity it is possible to use a css selector:

```
:disabled { opacity: 40%; }
```

However, to override the color of an icon it seems I have to resort to something extremely specific like and use !important

```
.application--light .icon.icon--disabled { color: blue!important; }
```

Take a look at [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/6hqo04Lc/26/). Is there some way to set the color of a disabled v-icon with a property of the v-icon, or with a simpler selector and without using !important?

Comment: Maybe something like this can be use ```<v-icon v-bind:color="(false) ? 'red' : 'blue'">home</v-icon>```. It work on the example you provide. You can also use a computed property ```<v-icon v-bind:color="computedProperty()">home</v-icon>``` that will return the color.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Vuetify does not allow CSS styles for most of its components, `v-icon` included, that's why you should add `!important` to override the default styles set by Vuetify.

However, you can customize the Vuetify colors creating an external `.js` file.

I recommend reading the theme configuration documentation provided by Vuetify:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#customizing